# Display ticket type progress in milestone

Tags: trac

just a little question here: How can I add different ticket types to be displayed in milestone description? Like the Bugs/Feature Requests on this page: https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GroupTicketFieldsPlugin

Comment: Also discussed on [trac-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/trac-users/R2C-iCTudfk/n7rVidSVh2MJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was solved by @RjOllos.

Usage: **[[TicketQuery(component=GroupTicketFieldsPlugin,group=type,format=progress)]]**